# Laravel - Localhost return array but server return object

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have same code running in localhost + server, but the response from Laravel is different.

In localhost, I get an `array`.
In server, I get an `object`.

I don't know why, because this never happen.

I'm using **Laravel 5.7.x** and the default `response()->json(...)` method.

---

## CODE

**LOCALHOST** (Windows 10, php 7.3.14)

```
  "departments": [
    {
      "name": "Sem departamento",
      "vacancies": [
        {
          "id": 264,
          "title": "OFICIAL DE MANUTENÇÃO PREDIAL (REFRIGERAÇÃO)",
          "pcd": 0,
          "internal_code": null,
          "company_department_id": 0,
          "exam_filename": null,
```

**Server (DigitalOcean)** (Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.3.11)

```
  "departments": {
    "0": {
      "name": "Sem departamento",
      "vacancies": [
        {
          "id": 74,
          "title": "Técnico de Sistemas Júnior",
          "pcd": 0,
          "internal_code": null,
          "company_department_id": 0,
          "exam_filename": null,
```

---

### Script

```php
        $departments[0] = [
            'name' => 'Sem departamento',
            'vacancies' => []
        ];
        foreach ($vacancies as $v) {
            if (empty($v->companyDepartment)) {
                $departments[0]['vacancies'][] = $v;
            } elseif (empty($departments[$v->companyDepartment->id])) {
                $departments[$v->companyDepartment->id] = [
                    'name' => $v->companyDepartment->name,
                    'vacancies' => [$v]
                ];
            } else {
                $departments[$v->companyDepartment->id]['vacancies'][] = $v;
            }
        }

        return response()->json(compact('departments'));
```

Comment: it's better to paste the code that results for this output

Comment: Show the code that generates `departments`. This is likely caused by an array indexing issue; JavaScript/JSON doesn't like arrays with non-0-based indicies, which can happen when you modify a Collection/Array in Laravel/PHP before calling `response()->json()` on it.

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja post updated

Comment: @TimLewis post updated

Comment: You can probably solve this by calling `return response()->json(['departments' => array_values($departments)])`, but your indicies won't reflect `$department->id`. You'll probably want to add `'id' => $v->companyDepartment->id` to your array generation and reference that in your JavaScript.

Comment: @TimLewis I'll try that now.

Comment: @TimLewis works! Thank you. But I don't understand why this error does not occur locally

Comment: Different database; different results (most likely). If you have an associative array in PHP, `[0 => ..., 2 => ...]`, it will be converted to an Object in JavaScript (`0: { }, 2: { }`), since the concept of associative arrays doesn't exist in JS. `0, 1` is fine, as it's sequential, 0-based, so there are definitely cases where this can happen unexpectedly.

Comment: On top of that it is very hard to figure out what your script is actually doing and you are probably over complicating it for yourself. I very seldom has to tinker with array indices, there is probably a better way :)